# Vary font size in Metapost

Tags: tex-core, metapost

I would like to vary font sizes in Metapost ... like

```
draw btex \small Text etex shifted(0cm, 1cm)
```

and so on ... but cannot work out how to do this. Is there a way?

Comment: It works the way you wrote it…

Comment: For what it's worth (as this is the top result for queries like [metapost label font size]) note that if you're not using `btex … etex`, then the [infont operator](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf#page=27) can take a `scaled`, like `label("foo" infont defaultfont scaled w` or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use LaTeX for `btex...etex` snippets, which you can do by calling

```
mpost -tex=latex
```

Here's a demonstration using the `gmp` package for direct comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape,latex]{gmp}

\begin{document}

\makebox[3cm][l]{\Huge Text}%
\makebox[3cm][l]{\Large Text}%
\makebox[3cm][l]{Text}%
\makebox[3cm][l]{\footnotesize Text}

\begin{mpost}
draw \btex \Huge Text etex;
draw \btex \Large Text etex shifted(3cm,0cm);
draw \btex Text etex shifted(6cm,0cm);
draw \btex \footnotesize Text etex shifted(9cm,0cm);
\end{mpost}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, in ConTeXt, you don't need to add `btex .. etex` tags. By default, all labels are typeset using TeX. Here is an example:

```
\starttext

\startMPpage[offset=1em]
  label.top("\tfc Text", origin);
  label.top("\tfb Text", (3cm,0));
  label.top("\tfa Text", (6cm,0));
  label.top("Text", (9cm,0));
  label.top("\tfx Text", (12cm,0));
\stopMPpage

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]